# Send Skype for Business message to online users at a specific IP address

Tags: skype-for-business

I do a lot of remote support work for a client and occasionally need to ask somebody to power-up a laptop (WOL is not consistent) that's on a desk either powered off or suspended. I currently send a Skype for Business instant message to everyone but this isn't ideal:

1. It goes to everyone whether they are currently online or not - would prefer to only go to those online
2. It goes to everyone no matter where they are, i.e. in the office, working from home or on the road - would prefer to go to everyone at the office
3. If they miss the message, they get it later in missed conversation. Would prefer this to not happen

Everyone at the office has the same IP address so that could be used to achieve #2 reasonably well but is suspect there isn't functionality to do this in the GUI. But is there a PowerShell solution?

Comment: Don't send it to everyone but to someone on site? How would everyone have the same IP? Maybe the same external IP but I doubt they have the same IP internal or are you talking about a range?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box this isn´t possible with Skype. You might come up with a fancy SfB powershell script, which check a given list of users and then send only the users who have a special state a message, however this required access to the SfB server in order to run the powershell script.

Then you might wish to write something on your own based on UCWA for example which did that. But this might be an overkill for you.

Last but least Microsoft is running an Skype for Business (=SFB) Feedback community, which you can access [here](https://www.skypefeedback.com/). So you might wish to post your idea and maybe Microsoft will pick that up and implement such a kind of feature.